# Finding Duplicate value in 2d array 3x3 magic Square

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

Im trying to create a 2D array 3x3 square.

Calculation and checking for it is done.
Right now, am trying to prevent repeated numbers from happening in the 2d array.

I tried using a for loop to brute force but cygwin compiles gives me error

Below is my code.
How do i go about checking 2d array?

```
    #include <stdio.h> /* printf */

    /*Preprocessor*/
    /*set N constant 3*/
    #define N 3
    typedef enum {false,true}
    bool;

int main()
{
   /*initialize size to 3*/
   int size =3;
   int sum, sum1, sum2,array[N][N];
   int row, col = 0;

   int i, j, duplicate =0;


   /* variable to 
   indicate process reached*/
   int checkf =0;



   /*input into the array of an array*/
   for(row =0; row <size; row++)
   {
     for(col =0; col < size; col++)
     {
       scanf("%d", &array[row][col]);
     }
   }

   **/*check for repeated values*/
   for(row =0; row<9; row++)
  {
    for(col=0; col <9; col++)
    {
      if(array==array[row][col])
    }      
   }**







 /*Diagonal*/
 /*sum of diagonal from the left 
 equals to sum of diagonal 
 from the right */
  /*initialize sum2 to 0*/
   sum2 =0;
   /*check if row less than 3*/
   for(row=0; row< size; row++)
   {
     /*check if col less than 3*/
    for(col=0;col<size; col++)
     {
       /*number of row 
       equals number of col*/
       if(row == col)
       {
       /*addition*/
       sum2 = sum2 + array[row][col]; 
       }
     }
   }

 /*row*/
   /*check if row less than 3*/
   for(row=0; row < size; row++)
   {
     /*initialize sum */
     sum = 0;
     /*check if col less than 3*/
      for(col=0; col <size; col++)
      {
       /*addition of numbers*/
       sum = sum + array[row][col];
      }
     /*check if all additions
     adds up to same sum*/
     if(sum2 == sum)
     {
      /*a flag or check to print*/
      checkf =1;
     }
     else
     {
      /*a flag or check to print*/
      checkf =0;
      break;
     }  
   }

   /*Columns*/

   /*check if row less than 3*/
   for(row = 0; row < size; row++)
   {
     /*initialize sum */
     sum1 =0;
     /*check if col less than 3*/
     for(col = 0; col < size; col++)
     {
       /*addition*/
       sum1 = sum1 + array[col][row];
     }
     /*sum of diagonal equals
     sum of columns*/
     if(sum == sum1)
     {
       /*a flag or check to print*/
       checkf =1;
     }
     else
     {
       /*a flag or check to print*/
       checkf =0;
       break;
     }
   }


   /*if statement is true
   prints and display*/
   if(checkf ==1)
   {
     printf("This is a magic square.\n");
   }
   else
   {
     /*print and display*/
     printf("This is not a magic square.\n");
   }
   return 0;

}
```

Comment: "_but cygwin compiles gives me error_" -- What's the error? The error message is *very* useful to us.

Comment: `if(array==array[row][col])` doesn't look right. You need two more loops to check. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14879569/3049655)

Comment: hi cool guy! i tried applying the logic from that before. im confused on how the i and j works.

Answer (score 1):

If you had a flat, one-dimensional array (of fixed size `N`, say), you would check all elements against every element to its left:

```
int unique1d(int array[N])
{
    int i, j;

    for(i = 1; i < N*N; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (array[i] == array[j]) return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;    
}
```

You can do the same for a two-dimensional array, when you "flatten" the indices first. Say you enumerate the cells of your 3×3 grid with "flat" indices like so:

```
0   1   2
3   4   5
6   7   8
```

Then you get:

```
flat = row * N + col;
```

and, conversely:

```
row = flat / N;      // truncating int division gives row
col = flat % N;      // remainder gives column
```

So a function that tests whether there are duplicates in your `N`×`N` grid would look like this:

```
int unique(int array[N][N])
{
    int i, j;

    for(i = 1; i < N*N; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (array[i / 3][i % 3] == array[j / 3][j % 3]) return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;    
}
```

I've made that into a separate function, because it makes the code clearer. Not how you don't need a separate flag and a `break`. You can return the result explicitly as soon as you have found it. (Also, the `break` would have to break out of a nested loop, but the `break` keyword in C just jumps out of the inner loop.)

(The rest of your code that checks whether the square is magic or not looks a bit suspicious, too. For example, you should start with the assumption that the square is magic and then set your flag to `false` if one of the conditions for a magic square doesn't hold. You never have to set that flag back to `true` again. But that's a topic for another question.)

**Edit**: In order to explain the function better, here's example client code. This is essentially your program without the magic check. `N` must be a defined constant, as it is in your program.

```
int main()
{
    int array[N][N];
    int row, col;

    for(row =0; row < N; row++) {
        for(col =0; col < N; col++) {
            scanf("%d", &array[row][col]);
        }
    }

    if (unique(array)) {
        puts("Values are unique");
    } else {
        puts("There are duplicate values.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: shouldnt i call a function that has an 2d array with a pointer?

Comment: q1.c: In function ‘repeatedValues’:
q1.c:37:5: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast
     return 1;
     ^
q1.c: In function ‘main’:
q1.c:49:5: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
    p=array[N][N];
     ^
q1.c:53:4: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wpedantic]
    int checkf =0;
    ^
q1.c:66:19: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘repeatedValues’ from incompatible pointer type
    repeatedValues(p);
                   ^
q1.c:26:6: note: expected ‘int (*)[3]’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
 int *repeatedValues(int array[N][N])

Comment: @GeraldLee Try `int repeatedValues(int array[N])` instead of `int* repeatedValues(int array[N][N])` or just use `int repeatedValues(int array[N][N])` and call the function with `repeatedValues(array);`. BTW, `p=array[N][N];` doesn't look right. Maybe you wanted `int* p = *array;`?

Comment: I've added an example `main`, so that you can see how to use the function. Please don't just paste error messages into the comments; it's unreadable and also not useful in absence of your code.

Comment: Hi Oehm, Sorry for the error messages. So basically what you are trying to do is that u call in a function into main.
Once it is called, it will check for the condition inside the function, and printf or do certain action accordingly?

Comment: @cool guy, would it have work if i use pointers to call an function to an array?

Comment: Yes. The function's job is just to decide whether the values are unique or not and to return an according value. Your "cleint code", that is the code that uses the function can then act on the returned information. In the short example above, the result is just used to print on of two sentences. In your program, you might want to write an error message and abort (or just decide the square isn't magic) when the values are not unique and silelntly carry on otherwise.

Comment: The code already used pointers behind the scenes. An Array "decays" into a pointer to its first element when you pass it to a function. Two-dimensional arrays aren't any different, but the elements of `array` ar themselves `int` arrays of size three. That's the `int (*)[3]` that you see in the error message. (But for now, don't worry too much about that.)